# Java JFrame: Update GUI during an event (not within a timer)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, repaint, actionevent

Been trying at this a little while, going no where fast. I have elements in a JFrame that I want to update/toggle viability for when I click my play button (which triggers the ActionEvent). However, these only seem to be updating **after the actionPerformed method is finished**. This is what I think is happening because the constructor for my SoundPlayer object triggers (Thread.sleep)s, causing a noticeable delay. I did read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007369/jframe-not-updating-before-thread-sleep) that using Thread.sleep() locks up a GUI, but I make my changes **before** calling SoundPlayer, so I don't think that would be the issue.

As seen below, I've tried repainting the JFrame in general, as well as the individual element. These do not update until after the SoundPlayer's delay is finished, though my println statement prints a the correct time.

MultiThreading has crossed my mind as a solution, though I don't see why I would need to do so. Any help on this matter is appreciated!

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    int channel = 0, volume = 0;    //Assigned for safety.
    String musicNotes = "";   //Will be filled with the under-input.
    boolean willPlay = true;    //Assumes will be played.

    /*Stuff that makes 'willPlay' either true of false*/

    //If nothing is wrong, plays the String!
    if (willPlay) {       //If above parameters are good...
        badNums.setVisible(false);
        prog.setVisible(true);

        if (vis.isSelected())
            prog.setText("Estimated duration: " + estiDuration(musicNotes)*(0.4) + "seconds");
        else
            prog.setText("Duration: " + estiDuration(musicNotes)*(0.3) + "seconds");

        System.out.println("test");
        repaint();
        prog.repaint();

        new SoundPlayer(channel, volume, musicNotes);          //Plays the music!
    } else {
        vis.setVisible(false);
        badNums.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is single threaded - all code for painting, events, etc... runs on this Thread (called the EDT). If you have a long running task and place it on the EDT, it can do nothing else until it is complete (note that calling `repaint` doesn't directly `repaint` the `Component`, so running something lengthy after this call does not mean the `Component` will actually paint itself before). If you need to perform lengthy operations, do so in a different `Thread` - this can be accomplished either directly using a [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html), or using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). If the former, be sure any calls to Swing get dispatched to the EDT using `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX`

Comment: Great, thanks. After trying to incorporate the SwingWorker I went back to Thread which I do know and it worked like a charm without too much extra editing! Now I should be able to revisit my original goal of updating the progress of my String processing during my sound playing!